# Out of memory issue with Archive::Tar module

Tags: perl, perl-module, mod-perl

I am doing a tar file extraction using `Archive::Tar` in Windows. The script is working fine most cases, but while encountering a big tar file it is throwing an out of memory error. I heard that this is known issue with this module.

Do you know if there is any way to resolve this issue ?

Comment: are you running this in `mod_perl`?

Answer (score 2):

This is because `Archive::Tar` reads the given tar file into memory.

> Use `Archive::Tar->iter` which returns an iterator function that reads
>   the tar file without loading it all in memory. Each time the function
>   is called it will return the next file in the tarball. The files are
>   returned as Archive::Tar::File objects. The iterator function returns
>   the empty list once it has exhausted the files contained.

Also check out

> `Archive::Tar::Streamed` - Tar archives, non memory resident
>
> `Archive::Tar::Wrapper` -  API wrapper around the 'tar' command line
>   utility. It never stores anything in memory, but works on temporary
>   directory structures on disk instead.

Update based on comment:

```
my $next = Archive::Tar->iter( "example.tar.gz", 1, {filter => qr/\.pm$/} ); #apply the filter here, what type of files do you want to iterate over

while( my $f = $next->() ) {
    print $f->name, "\n";

    $f->extract or warn "Extraction failed"; #here you can apply your logic by putting if else blocks

    # ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chankey!!!
I have very less knowledge about this module so to be more clear on this issue, I have list of files that I want to extract.
so if I use Archive::Tar->iter how I will match the file name with the list and files inside tar and if there is a match it will extract ?